# Sabre PassengerDetailsRQ not return the ID attribute in ItineraryRef

Tags: sabre

I am trying to book an air segment using EnhancedAirBookRQ and PassengerDetailsRQ using development endpoint.
But in the response I did not get the ID it just sending the information like

```
<ItineraryRef AirExtras="false" InhibitCode="U" PartitionID="AA" PrimeHostID="1S">
```

but i should return like `<ItineraryRef AirExtras="false" ID="DJEJWQ" InhibitCode="U" PartitionID="AA" PrimeHostID="1S">`

Is there any reason for this? bellow is my request XML code.

```
<PassengerDetailsRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_4" version="3.4.0">
   <PostProcessing >
      <RedisplayReservation waitInterval="1000"/>
   </PostProcessing>
   <PreProcessing />
   <SpecialReqDetails>
      <SpecialServiceRQ>
         <SpecialServiceInfo>
            <AdvancePassenger SegmentNumber="A">
               <Document ExpirationDate="2018-05-26" Number="1234567890" Type="P">
                  <IssueCountry>FR</IssueCountry>
                  <NationalityCountry>FR</NationalityCountry>
               </Document>
               <PersonName DateOfBirth="1980-12-02" Gender="M" NameNumber="1.1">
                  <GivenName>JAMES</GivenName>
                  <MiddleName>MALCOLM</MiddleName>
                  <Surname>GREEN</Surname>
               </PersonName>
            </AdvancePassenger>
         </SpecialServiceInfo>
      </SpecialServiceRQ>
   </SpecialReqDetails>
   <TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
      <AgencyInfo>
         <Address>
            <AddressLine>SABRE TRAVEL</AddressLine>
            <CityName>SOUTHLAKE</CityName>
            <CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
            <PostalCode>76092</PostalCode>
            <StateCountyProv StateCode="TX"/>
            <StreetNmbr>3150 SABRE DRIVE</StreetNmbr>
            <VendorPrefs>
               <Airline Hosted="true"/>
            </VendorPrefs>
         </Address>
      </AgencyInfo>
      <CustomerInfo>
         <ContactNumbers>
            <ContactNumber NameNumber="1.1" Phone="817-555-1212" PhoneUseType="H"/>
         </ContactNumbers>
         <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" NameReference="ABC123" PassengerType="ADT">
            <GivenName>MALCOLM</GivenName>
            <Surname>GREEN</Surname>
         </PersonName>
      </CustomerInfo>
   </TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
</PassengerDetailsRQ>
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any additional error messages?

Comment: No, I did not get any error message Except the return XML.

Comment: can you post the request/response for the airbookrq? and what carrier are yur trying to book? might have to take out hosted airline = true